# DllImport Error: winspool.drv missing in Mono?

Tags: c#, printing, raspberry-pi, mono, dllimport

I have an application running on Raspbian that uses `RawPrinterHelper.cs` (https://github.com/andyyou/SendToPrinter/blob/master/Printer/RawPrinterHelper.cs) to send raw ZPL print commands over USB to a Zebra label printer. Works fine on Windows.

I get the following error on Raspbian:

```
    System.DllNotFoundException: winspool.Drv
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) App.RawPrinterHelper:OpenPrinter (string,intptr&,intptr)
  at App.RawPrinterHelper.SendBytesToPrinter (System.String szPrinterName, System.IntPtr pBytes, System.Int32 dwCount) [0x00032] in <8ba638cb2422469187f74f936946c4cb>:0 
  at App.RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter (System.String szPrinterName, System.String szString) [0x0000f] in <8ba638cb2422469187f74f936946c4cb>:0
```

I've searched for similar problems, and found an article on Mono's website suggesting to use MONO_LOG_LEVEL to see which files Mono is looking for and then searching for those files in `/usr`. I get the following file names in the log, but don't find any of these in `/usr`.

```
Mono: DllImport attempting to load: 'winspool.Drv'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/usr/lib/libwinspool.Drv': '/usr/lib/libwinspool.Drv: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/usr/lib/libwinspool.Drv.so': '/usr/lib/libwinspool.Drv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library 'libwinspool.Drv': 'libwinspool.Drv: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library 'libwinspool.Drv.so': 'libwinspool.Drv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library 'winspool.Drv': 'winspool.Drv: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is for Windows only and uses p/invoke to call into the Windows API. You will need to find an alternative way to communicate with the device on Raspbian.

Comment: Will look for another way. Thanks.

Comment: In case someone else comes upon this, I ended up writing the zpl code to a .zpl file, installing CUPS and making a bash call in my application: `string bashCommand = "lp -d Zebra_Technologies_ZTC_ZD410-203dpi_ZPL -o raw /home/pi/label.zpl"; 
            Process.Start("/bin/bash", "-c \"" + bashCommand + "\"");`